# Using a UPS on 3-prong, ungrounded outlets and worrying voltage leak

Tags: grounding, ups

it seems this question is rather common. I live in a rented appartment built 70+ years ago. Back then, the building was built on a budget, and it was code-compliant to have ungrounded 1-phase 120VAC outlets (still visible in corridors), and apparently still is. It is NOT a split 240VAC. However, somewhere in its life, the original 2-prongs outlets were replaced with 3-prong versions, but still ungrounded. Most probably it was an easy way to plug in modern electric devices.

Since there's no requirement from code to upgrade older installations, there's no way I could convince the landlord to rewire everything.

On the other hand, as the electrical grid isn't exactly reliable, I want to upgrade my small UPS from a 500VA unit to a 1500VA unit. The problem is, every manufacturer write in big, bold letters "Do not operate without a ground present, hae an electrician perform the necessary job", ignoring what's still code-compliant and all those places that people don't own.
**Is that a simple safety warning as I read most of the time, or a real functionality requirement?** Only two loads have a grounding pin (a monitor and a switching power supply that powers all low-voltage peripherals)
So that's problem #1.

**Problem #2:**
A previous 1500VA CyberPower UPS I had used so far failed after just over 3 years of life (so convenient, the warranty is only 3 years sharp…) in a rather frightening way: a minute the general breaker trips. The following, the UPS doesn't kick in (a completely dead battery after 3 years after rather light usage? Please. - I deliberately oversized the capacity since the load is less than 100W). Unplugging everything, I try to turn it back on, and get a series of loud pops, hisses and foul-smelling smoke. As it was out of warranty anyway, I disconnected the battery and opened the UPS without touching any metal part, and out of the 8 MOSFETs, 6 were burnt beyond recognition.
**Could this has anything to do with ungrounded outlets? Or just a low quality UPS?** To this day, CyberPower customer's service fails to recognize the seriousness of a UPS failing destructively in the absence of a load or grid issue. Dead batteries don't make a UPS self-destruct.

**Third problem:**
Between ground from the UPS side (**not** the wall outlet side) and the hot water radiator, there's anywhere between 40VAC and the full 120VAC. That's a real safety hazard, but I don't know how to find the source.
Another set of measurements I made: I don't have a plug tester, but measured the following:

- Hot-to-radiator: 3VAC
- Neutral-to-radiator: 108VAC
- Ground-to-radiator: hovering around 55VAC

Would it mean that:

1. The hot and neutral wire are reversed in the outlet
2. The hot water radiator pipes are used as either a neutral or ground
   return path?
3. What else?

I know that COLD water pipes were sometimes used as ground, but it is forbidden now. Never heard about HOT water pipes being used for anything electrical. Same goes for neutral-as-ground as it isn't a true ground.

---

**UPDATE**

And, I finally bought a GFCI tester. As expected, all outlets show “open ground”.

Voltage measured from the receptacle:

- Line-to-cold water pipe: 106VAC approximately
- Neutral-to-cold water pipe:
- 0V Ground-to-cold water pipe: 0V, but probably meaningless since ground is unconnected.

But something curious also: Line-to-hot water pipe and Line-to-radiator is also 106VAC. More of a concern, actually, as the UPS and electronic equipment sits very close to the radiator (not worried about heat though, as it’s right up against the colder wall.). And no, there’s no other space for it, and especially not the proverbial “closet”. I realize these measurements are completely different from the first ones.

I wouldn’t bet on the pipes being all-metal to the street. The landlord consistently replaces leaking and clogged pipes by plastic ones.

Testing the replacement UPS yields some interesting result: only the red light turns on, a combination that’s not documented. Sometimes, I get the two first lights turned on, but that is still illogical as it would require a connected ground to light up. (Note: nevermind the two last ones, I traced it down to a likely fried MOV inside one of the power bars. I removed them and all plugs tested open ground afterwards, just doesn’t light up the switch, though)

As for problem #2, it has been solved in the meantime: Apparently someone at CyberPower took notice of the seriousness of a UPS going up in smoke and agreed to replace the UPS out-of-warranty. The UPS isn’t the business-expensive double conversion model, so currently only runs through the battery when an outage occurs (line interactive). According to the manufacturer, AVR is mostly done without battery power.At the time of the UPS failure, there was no spike. I still have an incandescent light and it didn’t burn nor change in intensity as it does when the microwave is turned on.

Comment: 1 - What jurisdiction are you in (country/state/city) as that determines current codes in effect? 2 - What you are seeing from the UPS side is interesting (and sounds bad) but not really what you should look at. What do you get *from a receptacle* to the cold water pipe? More importantly, is there a voltage showing (or no continuity at all) between neutral and ground in the receptacles? 3 - Are the receptacles installed in metal boxes connected to metal conduit? (If so, *the metal conduit **is** your ground*).

Comment: It would seem putting in 3-prong outlets **with the ground unconnected** is likely in violation of electrical codes, whether or not the building was "grandfathered", **because that was a change in the original (i.e., grandfathered) wiring**! It is also a safety hazard, because it deceives one using the outlet into thinking it is safely grounded, *when in actuality it is not*. Consult local officials for a remedy.

Comment: Current and many prior code versions (I don’t remember the year first added) require GFCI protection to change a non grounded receptacle to a 3 prong. Could the damage be from lack of a ground? Possibly. The ground provides a clean path back to ground for surge protection to use with out that a spike or surge on the line could have be the cause of your FET’s going up in smoke. Is 3 years a short time? It depends on the system many / most UPS’s run off the battery voltage all the time so when the power goes out there is no switching. Some brands the battery(s) are replaced @ 3-4 years.

Comment: can you measure the current between neutral and the radiator? voltage alone can be virtually meaningless.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact That’s in Canada, QC, Montreal. Electrical code is national, though, as I understand it. I get the safety hazard, but the city doesn’t really care: they never returned the call when I asked them to give me a final answer whether a pilot light was required or strictly forbidden on gas cooking appliances. But I digress. As for the electrical boxes, I wouldn’t be surprised if a previous landlord just changed the outlets without changing the wiring (2-wire rubberised cloth, no grounding wire, no metal conduit.)

Comment: @dandavis There’s no way I am putting my multimeter probes between two parts that shouldn’t be energized yet have a large potential difference.

Comment: ok, try a piece of wire first. if it doesn't get hot it's safe to probe with a DMM.